# Copy multiple source files and folders with only one showUI:=FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs

Tags: .net, vb.net, copy, deep-copy

There are many methods for copy or move files and directories in dotnet. 
for example:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory
```

only accept one sourceDirectoryName. But I want a special method to copy (or move) an array of path with only one progressbar dialog like command below

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.Copy(sourceDirectoryName:=new string (){"",""},  destinationDirectoryName:="", showUI:=FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)
```

I don't want to copy (or move) my sources one by one. because if I do this, a progressbar dialog appears for each command. And also I want to do something like windows progress dialog and handle all errors by OS, not my own. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do that without using native Windows API or some 3rd party library.

Comment: Native windows API is OK. but how ? any references ? I find no glue on the net .